# Python - Counting the occurence of lists in a list (collections, counter)

Tags: python, list, collections, nested, counter

I imported collections

```
import collections
```

I use it to count the occurence of certain strings in a list

```
counts = collections.Counter(list)
counts = counts.most_common()
```

This works perfectly fine. Now my needs changed and I have a nested list and I want to count the occurence of lists in that list:

```
lists = [['word1', 'word2'], ['word4', 'word6'], ['word1', 'word2']]
```

I get "lists" from a list of single words:

```
list = ['word1', 'word2', ...]
```

The result should look like this

```
[(('word1', 'word2'), 2), (('word4', 'word6'), 1)]
```

I hope it is clear what I want.

Comment: If that's a list of tuples, as in your example, what's stopping you? Counter should work just fine. Otherwise, convert the nested lists to tuples first.

Comment: whatever that you have mentioned in your questions(above mentioned code), it works fine to get your expected result.

Comment: @mgruber : Check my solution

Comment: See my edit. Do the brackets change anything? btw: I checked it and it works for the [( ), ( ), ...] But as I edited I have brackets only

Answer (score 3):

[`collection.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) works perfectly fine. Below is the example you mentioned:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = [('word1', 'word2'), ('word4', 'word6'), ('word1', 'word2')]

>>> Counter(my_list)
Counter({('word1', 'word2'): 2, ('word4', 'word6'): 1})  # dict object

>>> Counter(my_list).most_common()  
[(('word1', 'word2'), 2), (('word4', 'word6'), 1)]
```

Comment: Counter.items() does not guarantee order the way Couner.most_common() does, and of which the OP is already aware.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hashing` using `dict()`. This is a simple code illustrating it:

```
lists = [('word1', 'word2'), ('word4', 'word6'), ('word1', 'word2')]

hashmap = dict()
for item in lists:
    if item in hashmap:
        hashmap[item] += 1
    else:
        hashmap[item] = 1


new_list = []

for key, value in hashmap.iteritems():
    new_list.append(((key), value))

print new_list  # output: [(('word1', 'word2'), 2), (('word4', 'word6'), 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just manage to answer the question on my own. 
The problem was that it was a list of lists.
I needed to have a list of tupples to get Counter working.

I managed to do that while collecting the words from the list of words:

... tuple(words[i:i+2])